# client_body_buffer_size threats

Tags: nginx

in my current nginx configuration I got:

```
client_max_body_size          100M;
client_body_buffer_size       1M;
```

client_max_body_size I need to be set so big.
Unlucky I often got notices when ppl upload files.

```
[warn] 790#0: *112386 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file
```

As I found online - raise "client_body_buffer_size" config value will help. But first I would like to find out what threats it will couse.

The DOS attack will be easier? Nginx will need more space for all requests? something else?